# Netbeans GUI Background Color Change on Button Press

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans

I'm using Netbeans 6.7.1. I'm making a GUI application.

What I want to have happen when I press a button (btnEnter, I named it) is for the background color of my application to change (not the color of the button, but of the mainPanel). Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Go try it out, then come back with the code you tried and a specific question about it. You should probably start by reading this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html

Comment: NetBeans 6.7.1 is quite old. Insist upon using 7.x.

Answer (score 0):

Quicky one: 
 i assume u have already created a jframe and inside u have the button.

1.in design mode select the jButton and on the right property panel go to the events. find the onclick event of the jbutton
 2. in the method the netbeans creates in your code window go and write :

`jFrame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.Green);`

With this u tell the application when u click the button change the color of the jFrame. Offcourse u have to change the name to what u r using i.e. i use jFrame but you may have called it xFramex. so u have to write it as :

```
xFramex.getContentPane().setBackgroundcolor(Color.Green);
```

what u should know is that all containers(jPanel, JFrame etc) in java have the getContentPane() method for handing the colors and other styles.
If u dont want the default colors like i have shown above (Color.Green) then u have to change it to something like this :

`jFrame.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(128, 234, 10));`

The Color syntax is : Red (0-255), Green (0-255), Blue (0-255)
U can easily find the combination desired if u open the Paint app of windows and look the numbers in the color palette there.
Hope i helped a bit.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used to change the background using a button add this to your jbutton that I called blue

```
blue.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    System.out.println("blue.actionPerformed, event="+evt);
setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    getContentPane().setBackground(newjava.awt.Color(51,98,118));
                    }
```